# Scala ambiguous imports

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Scala beginner here and I was trying out the example here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sryza/aas/master/ch02-intro/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/intro/RunIntro.scala

> ```
> val nasRDD = parsed.map(md => {
>   md.scores.map(d => NAStatCounter(d))
> })
> ```

The above gives me error:

```
<console>:51: error: reference to NAStatCounter is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $VAL180.NAStatCounter
and import INSTANCE.NAStatCounter
             md.scores.map(d => NAStatCounter(d))
                            ^
```

Can anyone please explain why this double import is happening. How can I avert this?

Comment: can you add all your imports as well?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem.  I put RunIntro.scala into a small sbt project and compiled it successfully with the build.sbt file (with blank lines removed)

```
% cat build.sbt
name := "RunIntro"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= List("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.1")
```

The imports are only part of the source of your problem.  How are you compiling this source?